# Configurable URL with ACRA for Android when sending report to self hosted server?

Tags: android

I'm using [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/) for Android, and I want to send the crash reports to my own server. I've set it up alright, and everything works fine. However, I would like to make the URL that the reports are sent to configurable. But I do not know how to do it.

Here is the code I use to set the URL

```
    @ReportsCrashes(formKey = "", // will not be used
            formUri = "http://yourserver.com/yourscript",
            formUriBasicAuthLogin = "yourlogin", // optional
            formUriBasicAuthPassword = "y0uRpa$$w0rd", // optional
            mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
            resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text)
    public class MyApplication extends Application {
    ...
```

So basically, I wan't to be able to configure `formUri` from within the application. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I was a bit quick to post a question, because I found how to do it by myself... But the URL can be changed with the following line of code:

```
    ErrorReporter.getInstance().setReportSender(new HttpPostSender(newAddress, null));
```

**Edit: Old answer, see bendvds updated answer**

Answer (score 9):

It seems ErrorReporter.getInstance is now deprecated, but the following lines have the same effect. Execute them before calling ACRA.init.

```
ACRAConfiguration config = ACRA.getConfig();
config.setFormUri("http://server.com/script");
ACRA.setConfig(config);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to comment on benvd's answer, but I don't have a high enough reputation.

ACRA.getConfig() ignores all settings within @ReportsCrashes providing a completely blank config. ACRA.getNewDefaultConfig() returns a new config object with your build settings, but can still have the Uri changed dynamically.

```
ACRAConfiguration config = ACRA.getNewDefaultConfig();
config.setFormUri("http://server.com/script");
ACRA.setConfig(config);
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer for your question found on [ACRA : Advanced usage](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#dynamic-configuration)

> Every @ReportsCrashes parameter can also be set on runtime. This was needed since ADT 17 where Android Library Projects could not be used with ACRA due to their resources identifiers not being final fields anymore. Some advanced developers also needed to adjust ACRA parameters depending on user choices or when enablig special debug modes.
>
> The method ACRA.getConfig() returns an ACRAConfiguration object which provides a setter for each @ReportsCrashes configuration item.
>
> You can even use ACRA.getNewDefaultConfig(Application) to create a new configuration object initialized with default values + values set in your annotation parameters, modify some values, keep the object in memory for later use, and set it to ACRA.setConfig(ACRAConfiguration) when needed.